# Powershell is unable to find a package by name in a shared folder repository?

Tags: powershell, nuget

Please, observe:

```
C:\xyz\LogDbUpgradeProgress [master ≡]> Find-Package -Source \\devstatic\artifacts\nuget\packages -Name 'LogDbUpgradeProgress'
Find-Package : No match was found for the specified search criteria and package name 'LogDbUpgradeProgress'. Try Get-PackageSource to see all available
registered package sources.
At line:1 char:1
+ Find-Package -Source \\devstatic\artifacts\nuget\packages -Name 'LogD ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.Power...ets.FindPackage:FindPackage) [Find-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoMatchFoundForCriteria,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.FindPackage
```

But the package is there nonetheless and `Find-Package` is able to find it without filtering:

```
C:\xyz\LogDbUpgradeProgress [master ≡]> Find-Package -Source \\devstatic\artifacts\nuget\packages |? { $_.Name -eq 'LogDbUpgradeProgress' }

Name                           Version          Source           Summary
----                           -------          ------           -------
LogDbUpgradeProgress           1.0.0            xyz Repo         Logs the progress of the DbUpgrade tool to a file, which can later be used to send AppIns...


C:\xyz\LogDbUpgradeProgress [master ≡]>
```

How can I configure the system, so that `Find-Package` does find packages by name in a shared folder repository?

Comment: Weird, it works on my end, I'm using 5.1 version. You can try to add wildcards , like '\*DbUpgrade\*'  and see if it change anything

Comment: Interesting. Surrounding the name with starts actually works.